# Prove or disprove that if $f:X\longrightarrow Y$ is a perfect map then $w(Y)\le w(X)$

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, examples-counterexamples, cardinals

Let be $f$ a [perfect map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_map#Formal_definition) from a space $X$ to a space $Y$ so that I am trying to prove or disprove if the inequality
$$
\begin{equation}\tag{1}\label{1}w(Y)\le w(X)\end{equation}
$$
holds, where $w$ is the [weight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_(topology)#Weight_and_character). So, on this purpose, let be $\Lambda$ a collection with cardinality $\lambda$ and thus let we observe that the collection $\scr U(\Lambda)$ of finite union of $\Lambda$ has cardinality $\lambda$ because obviously $\Lambda$ is a subset of $\scr U(\Lambda)$ and because any finite union can be identified with a function from any $n\in\omega$ to $\lambda$ and viceversa so that
$$
|\mathscr U(\Lambda)|=\biggl|\bigcup_{n\in\omega}\lambda^n\biggl|\le\sum_{n\in\omega}\lambda^n\le\sum_{n\in\omega}\lambda^{n+1}=\sum_{n\in\omega}\lambda=\lambda\cdot\aleph_0=\lambda
$$
So let be $\mathcal B_X$ a base whose cardinality is $w(X)$ and thus let's we prove that the collection
$$
\mathcal B_Y:=\Big\{Y\setminus f\big[X\setminus U\big]:U\in \mathscr U(\mathcal B_X)\Big\}
$$
is a base for $Y$ whose cardinality is $w(X)$ so that let be $y$ and element of any open set $V$ of $Y$. So we observe that the inclusion
$$
f^{-1}[y]\subseteq f^{-1}[V]
$$
but continuity implies that $f^{-1}[V]$ is open so that for any $x\in f^{-1}[y]$ there exists $B_x\in\mathcal B_X$ such that
$$
x\in B_x\subseteq f^{-1}[V]
$$
so that by compactness of $f^{-1}[y]$ there exists $U\in\mathscr U(\mathcal B_X)$ such that
$$
f^{-1}[y]\subseteq U\subseteq f^{-1}[V]
$$
which implies that
$$
y\in Y\setminus f\big[X\setminus U\big]\subseteq f[U]\subseteq V
$$
so that we conclude that $\mathcal B_Y$ is a base. After all, $\mathcal B_Y$ is indexed on $\mathscr U(\mathcal B_X)$ whose cardinality is $w(X)$. So we conclude that
$$
w(Y)\le w(X)
$$

So first of all I ask if $\eqref{1}$ holds and so if it holds I ask if I prove it well. Moreover I ask if $f^{-1}[y]$ is Lindelöf then is it possible to relate $w(X)$ with $w(Y)$? indeed in this case $\mathscr U(\Lambda)$ became the subset of countable union of $\Lambda$ but I only know that
$$
\lambda\le\lambda^{\aleph_0}
$$
and the equality cannot be false so that I am not able to say something about $w(Y)$. Finally is it possible for $\eqref{1}$ be always a equality? So could someone help me, please?

Comment: Please define what you mean by perfect map.

Comment: And please stop saying "So could someone help me, please?".  In English it comes across as demanding. Better not say anything of that sort :-)

Comment: @PatrickR A perfect map is a continuous, closed, surjective map whose fibers are compact: anyway I edited the question adding a wiki-reference.

Comment: Your proof of (1) looks good, except that the definition in wikipedia that you refer to does not treat a finite topology as a special case.  When defining the weight, one usually takes it to be $\aleph_0$ if there is a finite base for the topology, which is probably needed in this.  Also, I am confused about your assertion with Lindelof.  Fibers are compact here, so there are always Lindelof.

Comment: @PatrickR Oh, I di non saw that Wikipedia do not required tha the weight is always infinite: so I now say explicitly that the weight is the minimum cardinality of a base plus $\aleph_0$. Moreover in the second part I was assuming that the fibers are only Lindelöf and not compact, that's all.